# Find the c.d.f. from the p.m.f

Tags: probability, cumulative-distribution-functions

Verify that the following p.m.f. is valid and if it is, then find its c.d.f.

$$\mathbb{P}(X=n)=\frac{1}{n(n+1)}\;\forall\;n\in\mathbb{N}^+$$

**My Attempt**
Verifying that it is valid is easy. I just need to check whether or not it sums to $1$. So
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n(n+1)}=1$$
We know that this infinite series is true, so our p.m.f. is valid. Now to find the c.d.f.. Since this p.m.f. is discrete, I will use the following formula:
$$F(t)=\sum_{k\in X, k\leq t}p(k)$$
My question is how should I divide the intervals so that I can write the c.d.f.? It is a piecewise function that changes with each $n$ so would my c.d.f. be
\begin{equation}
F(t)=
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } t\leq0\\
\frac{1}{1(1+1)} &\text{if } 0<t\leq1\\
\frac{1}{2(2+1)} &\text{if } 1<t\leq2\\
...
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

This doesn't seem like a very good way to write the c.d.f. so I am wondering if there are other ways to express it.

Comment: Hint!!! [Try using induction](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-solve-1-2-1-6-1-12-1-20-1-30-1-9900/answer/Stewart-Gordon-6?ch=10&share=3b440d5e&srid=uOh0F) to show indeed that your desired CDF(n) = $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i(i+1)} = \frac{n}{n+1}$

Answer (score 1):

You can use induction  as pointed out in the hint, or you can see it as follows:

$$
\mathbb{P}(X\leq n) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i(i+1)}=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(i+1)-i}{i(i+1)} = \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{i} -\frac{1}{i+1} \right)= 1-\frac{1}{n+1}.
$$